# Opening a text field causes the parrent widget to rebuild

Tags: flutter, bloc

my app is structured like this:

```
    class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).add(const DashboardEvent());
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
```

The Main Page is responsible for navigation via the navigation bloc. Different buttons add different events depending on what page I want to show. Up to this point everything was working normally but all of sudden when I open any TextField in my app, it causes this main page to rebuild, calling the DashboardEvent and the page with the text field disappear.

I know that opening a TextField causes flutter to call the build method, but up to this point, in only caused the page to rebuild, not the parent widget. I have no idea why is it behaving like this all of sudden. Is there any setting I could toggle that I don't remember that could cause this behavior ? Thank you

Comment: It seems like a great usecase for `StatefulBuilder`. You can see quickly how does it work [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syvT63CosNE&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG&index=4). Let me know if it helped

Comment: @Wiktor I wrapped the body of the scaffold with the stateful builder but sadly the text field still rebuilds the whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
@override  
initState(){
    BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context).add(const DashboardEvent());
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot you could call stuff in initState!